# Referencing Android Documentation

Tags: citations, thesis, masters, reference-request

I would like to reference some material from Android documentation (such as [Sensor Events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) and [Sensors Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html)) into my M.Sc thesis, talking about the details of sensor services in Android.

What is the appropriate way of referencing such material? Should I use **endnotes** or **footnotes**? If using **endnotes**, what's the standard style?

I am using LaTeX and BibTeX for citations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the documentation is online (and apparently exclusively online), I would cite the website in question.

> Google and Open Handset Alliance n.d. Android API Guide. http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html. Accessed May 19, 2015.

See also [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page).

Comment: Thank for the response Koldito. Should I assume that it's better to use the same overall reference for anything from Android Documentation or it's better to use references fro different pages?

Comment: That it as difficult question. The answer depends on whether you want to consider the whole guide as a single document (with each page being a different "section") or whether you want to say that each page is an independent document. Personally, I would go for the first option, but I think you are more knowledgeable than me on this particular issue.

Comment: What about "Author" of a document, should it be Android or whom?